# Hide elements (<br><b></b><br>) in a column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using Knack Online Database to create apps. I'm trying to find a way to hide empty space in a cell.

I have a table that has a text formula. The text formula combines multiple fields (question and answers) and separates them using `<br>`. This is how i have it set up:

```
<b>question1</b> answer1
<br>
<b>question2</b> answer2
<br>
<b>question3</b> answer3
<br>
```

For some records, some of the fields are empty so this is how it results:

```
<b>question1</b> answer1
<br>
<b></b>
<br>
<b>question2</b> answer2
<br>
```

In my table, the empty space would show and it would take so much space:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjfdk.png)

I've tried using this code but it didn't work:

```
$(document).on('knack-view-render.view_2665', function(event, view, data) {
  removeWhiteSpaces('kn-input-field_3288');
});
```

I'm not sure what's the best solution to hide the empty space. Is there a code that I could use to hide the `<b></b><br>` if the `<b></b>` was empty for this column/field?

Comment: What is `removeWhiteSpaces` function doing? Also, could you provide bigger chunk of HTML? Namely, pieces related to `kn-input-field_3288` and `knack-view-render.view_2665`?

Comment: http://html-tuts.com/check-if-div-is-empty-html-element-has-children-tags/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like this in your CSS?

```
b:empty + br:empty,
b:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

This would hide every empty `<b>` tag and any empty `<br>` placed after an empty `<b>`.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udn4mfpy/).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this?

```
var empties = jQuery("b:empty");
var nextsBr = empties.next().filter('br');
nextBr.remove();
empties.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:empty` and siblings selectors

```js
$('b:empty').remove()

$('br + br').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>question1</b> answer1
<br>
<b></b>
<br>
<b>question2</b> answer2
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('b').each(function() {
    if ( $.trim( $(this).text() ).length == 0 ) {
        if ( $(this).children().length == 0 ) {
            $(this).text('');
            $(this).remove(); // remove empty paragraphs
        }
    }
});
```

Taken from [here](http://html-tuts.com/check-if-div-is-empty-html-element-has-children-tags/).