# hide parent element if doesnt contain child elements - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide parent element if his child doesn't contain content.

It doesn't give me any errors, but it just doesn't work at all...

My code is

```js
function hasElement(child, parent) {
  if (!child.length) {
    parent.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}

function hideGallery() {
  var child = document.querySelectorAll('.test'),
    parent = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
  if (parent === null) {
    return;
  }
  hasElement(child, parent);
}
  hideGallery()
```

```css
.hidden { display:none }

.test { height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">img
    <img src="1.png" alt="" class="img">
  </div>
  <div class="col test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet - please make it into a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, if doesnt contain text or images

Comment: `parent = document.querySelectorAll('.row');` is a nodelist. You need to use querySelector or loop

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList (possibly many elements) it doen't have `classList` you need to loop over items.

Comment: `.hidden [ display:none }` What is this?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt That was my mistake

Comment: Just yesterday was a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57081840/hide-elements-brb-bbr-in-a-column/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) CSS pseudo-class

**Note:** It doesn't work with whitespace

```js
if (document.querySelectorAll('.col:empty').length) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.row')[0].classList.add('hidden')
}
```

```css
.test:empty {
  display: none;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img src="1.png" alt="img" class="img">
  </div>
  <div class="col test"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Won't hide the parent though

Answer (score 0):

Your variables child and parent are Arrays. You could use `document.querySelector()` or `document.querySelectorAll()[0]` to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is loop through the parents and directly check the children inside the loop. If the children's length is 0, add the hidden class.

```
function hideEmptyParents(){
  const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
  parent.forEach(p => {
    const children = p.querySelectorAll('.col');
    if(children.length == 0) p.classList.add('hidden');
  })
}
```